# Парсинг String для построения динамического меню Android

Tags: java, android, json, строки, парсер

Сервер присылает json такого типа:

```
{
"session": {
    "operations": [{
        "url": null,
        "operationParams": {
            "operationPath": "App/Information/Information product",
            "operationImage": null,
            "placements": 0
        }
    }, {
        "url": null,
        "operationParams": {
            "operationPath": "App/Information/Information shop",
            "operationImage": null,
            "placements": 0
        }
    }, {
        "url": null,
        "operationParams": {
            "operationPath": "App/Information/Information dev/contancts",
            "operationImage": null,
            "placements": 0
        }
    },{
        "url": null,
        "operationParams": {
            "operationPath": "App/Information/Information dev/address",
            "operationImage": null,
            "placements": 0
        }
    }, {
        "url": null,
        "operationParams": {
            "operationPath": "App/reports/photo reports",
            "operationImage": null,
            "placements": 0
        }
    }, {
        "url": null,
        "operationParams": {
            "operationPath": "App/reports/photo reports/all photo",
            "operationImage": null,
            "placements": 0
        }
    }]
}}
```

Json очень упрощен для удобства.
В зависимости от того какой Json приходит нужно строить динамическое меню  ввиде обычного ListView.
для этого нужно разпарсить  строку типа: App/Information/Information product/contancts
где Information первый уровень , Information product второй уровень и contancts  третий уровень и т.д.
уровней может быть больше 5 так что захардкодить не вариант.

```
 String[] tempArray = menuLine.split("/");
```

так получалось разбить строку на пункты меню по сути но как сделать прикаждной итерации цыкла меню типа

```
Information  -Information product
             -Information shop
             -Information dev    -contancts
                                 -address
```

Ума не приложу как это сделать. Кто то сталкивался с подобным? как решали?

Comment: Не совсем понял в чем вопрос. Как распарсить такую строку? Переводите строку в char-массив и бежите по нему циклом, когда натыкатесь на "/", то начинается первый уровень, еще одна"/" - заканчивается первый уровень...и т.д.

Comment: Если вопрос состоит в самом парсинге файла, то Вы можете использовать JSON-Simple или Jakson

Comment: Если же Вам нужно разбить App/reports/photo reports/all photo эту строку то используйте функцию split("/"), она разобьет строку на массив строк по /, Вы получите его размер и все ок

Comment: Полагаю, тут два вопроса. Автор хочет услышать от нас полный цикл решения. Боюсь, я знаю только про парсинг. Для генерации меню программно, нужен другой советчек. А вопрос все-таки уточните.

Comment: @KostyaM да я так и делал в начале но как посотроить иерархию пунктов меню на пример 
Information - Information shop
                   - Information dev  -contancts
                                                - address

Comment: Вы меня только еще больше запутали))) Всмысле построить иерархию пунктов меню? Что должно получиться в итоге, приведите пример

Comment: @KostyaM
на примере json который я вставил то должно получиться лист вью где будет два пункта Information и reports
 по нажатию на Information мы или перебираем еще раз этот масив или я вот не знаю что делать но должно листвью пересоздаеться что бы  отображались новые пункты то есть Information product,Information shop,Information dev  по нажатию на Information dev листвью пересоздаеться и показывает юзеру contancts и address
по такой же схеме работать должны остальные пункты reports и т.д.